# Is there a way to drop all volatile tables with one command in Teradata?

Tags: sql, teradata

I've been looking to see if there's a shortcut way to drop all, or at least multiple, volatile tables with one command without logging out of the database.

This would be very handy for when I'm testing out & tweaking scripts, as it's often the case that I'll identify an issue that requires fixing in a volatile table multiple steps back in the script. This, currently, requires me to go back and drop each table one by one, which is a hassle.

Thanks!

Comment: No way besides Logoff & Logon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually do a `HELP VOLATILE TABLE` then paste the output to excel & concatenate a `DROP TABLE`then table name, then `;` and paste it back into teradata. Saves having to type it all out, or disconnect and re-enter password....

Answer (score 0):

Better and faster way: disconnect from teradata and reconnect...